# Python 2.7. Extracting data from some part of a string using a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Let's import a regex.

```
import re
```

Assume there's a string containing some data.

```
data = '''Mike: Jan 25.1, Feb 24.3, Mar 29.0
   Rob: Jan 22.3, Feb 20.0, Mar 22.0
   Nick: Jan 23.4, Feb 22.0, Mar 23.4'''
```

For example, we want to extract floats for Rob's line only.

```
name = 'Rob'
```

I'd make it like this:

```
def data_extractor(name, data):
    return re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', re.findall(r'{}.*'.format(name),data)[0])
```

The output is `['22.3', '20.0', '22.0']`.

Is my way pythonic or it should be improved somehow? It does the job, but I'm not certain about appropriateness of such code.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For me personally, I'd put the re.findall s on separate lines. First sets a value, second uses that value.  Sure you can one line it, but for down the road reading I like it a little more explicit.  Just my 2 cents

Comment: A possible problem is that each time data_extractor() is called it searches data from the beginning for the _name_. If it's an ad hoc query for a few arbitrary names, that's ok. But if you will be using _all_ the names, this is not efficient, because it runs through the same text territory every time.

Comment: Also, pythex is a good tool for testing python regex: http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-regex way consists in splitting the lines and trimming them, and then checking which one starts with `Rob` and then grab all the float values:

```
import re
data = '''Mike: Jan 25.1, Feb 24.3, Mar 29.0
   Rob: Jan 22.3, Feb 20.0, Mar 22.0
   Nick: Jan 23.4, Feb 22.0, Mar 23.4'''
name = 'Rob'
lines = [line.strip() for line in data.split("\n")]
for l in lines:
    if l.startswith(name):
        print(re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', l))
# => ['22.3', '20.0', '22.0']
```

See a [Python demo](http://rextester.com/LKRJ5081)

If you want to use a purely regex way, you may use a PyPi `regex` module with a `\G` based regex:

```
import regex
data = '''Mike: Jan 25.1, Feb 24.3, Mar 29.0
   Rob: Jan 22.3, Feb 20.0, Mar 22.0
   Nick: Jan 23.4, Feb 22.0, Mar 23.4'''
name = 'Rob'
rx = r'(?:\G(?!\A)|{}).*?(\d+\.\d+)'.format(regex.escape(name))
print(regex.findall(rx, data))
```

See the [online Python demo](http://rextester.com/TKCASW41062)

This pattern matches:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|{})` - the end of the last successful match or the `name` contents
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - Group 1 (just the value `findall` will return) matching 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits.

The `regex.escape(name)` will escape chars like `(`, `)` etc. that might appear in the `name`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never dealt with PyPi regex module so it's something to dive into.